# How to call Shortcode categories for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode, nivo-slider

Hi I'm trying to do something rather tricky in my Wordpress Theme
I'm more of a designer front-end developer so its a bit of a guess work with php.
Anyone have any ideas why this code only displays one slide. I want it to run a slideshow pulling in multipe slides from one category in my theme.

Thanks For your help

```
    //Add Nivo Short Codes
function nivo_slider_function($atts){

   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 5,
      'category' => ''
   ), $atts));

 $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'homepage_slider'
    );

    if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
        $args['category_name'] = $category;
    }

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $homepage_slider  = '<div id="slider">'; //Open the container
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) { // Generate the markup for each Question
        $homepage_slider .= sprintf(('<h3><a href="">%1$s</a></h3><div>%2$s</div>'),
            $post->post_title,
            wpautop($post->post_content)
        );
    }
    $homepage_slider .= '</div>'; //Close the container


   $return_string = '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';

   query_posts(array('post_type' => 'homepage_slider', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'showposts' => $posts));

   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();

         $slider_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'homepage-slide', false);
         $target_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'slide_target_link', true);   
         $return_string .= '<a href="'.$target_link.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="' . $slider_img_src[0] .'" /></a>';

      endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</div>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;

}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('slider-demo', 'nivo_slider_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're doing and there is an easier way of doing this. Replace your slider with [***SMART SLIDER 2***](http://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-slider-2/). It has different settings including one called dynamic. With this dynamic slider, you can use slides from a category within your site.

I discovered this just last week and I absolutely love the flexibility of this slider. It is rather heavy because of the different features it lets you do. So, if you are worried about that. Set it up as you would want it in a bogus WP site, strip the HTML, PHP, JS, and CSS and migrate it in your site's page. This obviously would be more work but you'll have a smaller code and you don't have to worry about figuring this out.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks but no thanks I'm trying to build it into my theme itself on purpose so don't want a plugin!

Comment: That's a nivo slider you're using.  Am I right? I'm suggesting a replacement to it.  But ok

Comment: Oh I see sorry was a little tired last night. I'll look into it, isn't there a stand along js file of it?

Comment: Sure there is. But that's like repairing your beat up old car when you can trade in for a new one that has all the features you want. AND for the same price! Look, honestly, anyone who is concerned about plugins shouldn't be using wordpress to begin with. You are already getting a lot of unused code straight out of the box. I don't think replacing one slider for another is going to make it worse

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't mean to seem rude. Totally appreciate the advice. I lean more towards design so a bit of a newbie to php coding. I agree the plugins are very feature rich. I managed to use bx slider in the end but just for a backup incase the plugin packs in and I have to source a new one. Will try out Smart slider as it looks amazing and more features than metaslider!